# VBPW34S vs BPW34S-Z key differences?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, datasheet, photodiode, component-selection

I have a circuit for detecting frequencies in light noise. Its a reverse bias mode circuit where the photodiode is coupled to a trans-impedance amplifyer circuit via a ceramic capacitor. I use it to detect frequencies in the 0-1000hz range, and it works reliably.

The original circuit uses Vishay VBP34 photodiodes. I want to some PCBs made, but my supplyer doesnt have the Vishay components in stock, only from OSRAM.

Is the OSRAM BPW34S-Z a direct replacement for the VBPW34S, or are there any important differences that might affect the performance of the circuit?

Please keep in mind, I am not an electrical engineer, just a hobbyist. So what might seem simple for others may not be simple for me.

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/392042/VISHAY/VBPW34S.html

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1336178/OSRAM/BPW34S-Z.html

Comment: You will get more input if you provide links the datasheets of the two components in question.

Answer (score 0):

They are compatible, but it's likely that there will be slight differences in whatever your measuring because things like the radiant sensitive area is different (BPW is 6% larger). The spectral responsivity is rougly the same. Some of the important parameters are not on both datasheets. One part is slightly larger, but you may be able to solder either in the place of the other, not sure on SMT solder. Best thing to do would be to test the new one and see if it will work for your application.